# How to hide the Facebook Login page activity after successful login in android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity

I am a newbiew in Android. I have intergarted `Facebook` in my `Android` app. I have a Login page with a button. On click of that button the FB login page appears.After the successful login of Facebook, the user gets to go to the MainActivity. I want to hide my Login page after the successful login of FB. That is, when I reload the app, if the user has already logged in then the MainActivity only should be dispalyed and not the Login page.

My code is as follows:

```
public class Login extends Activity {
private static final String URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=";

//private TextView textInstructionsOrLink;
 private ImageButton buttonLoginLogout;
 public static final String PREFS_PRIVATE = "PREFS_PRIVATE";
 private Button b;

private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
Databasehandler db=new Databasehandler(this);
HashMap<String, String>map=new HashMap<String, String>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    buttonLoginLogout = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }

    updateView();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
}



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

}
private void updateView() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final String t1=user.getId();
                final String t2=user.getName();
                 // SharedPreferences myPrefs =getSharedPreferences("myprefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                int count=db.getme();
                if(count==0)
                {
                map.put("uid",t1.toString());
                map.put("name",t2.toString());
                db.insertnewuser(map);
                }
    }
        });

      Intent ik=new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);

        ik.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(ik);
     } else {

        buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
        });
    }
}

private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}
  private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        updateView();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try below code and let me know if you find any difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Just add below code inside `updateView` method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

So your full method will look something like below code.

```
private void updateView() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final String t1=user.getId();
                final String t2=user.getName();
                 // SharedPreferences myPrefs =getSharedPreferences("myprefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                int count=db.getme();
                if(count==0)
                {
                map.put("uid",t1.toString());
                map.put("name",t2.toString());
                db.insertnewuser(map);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                }
    }
```

So basically it will automatically moves to next screen whenever facebook session is opened.

Answer (score 0):

//After successfull login it hide the facebook button

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  //after successful login into the facebook it hide the logout button
        loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

//if you want to logout after login to facebook successfully then you want to write this line inside the onSccess() method at the end


//after successful login into the facebook it hide the logout button


LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```